# Help me break down this 將 sentence

Tags: grammar

我傾向於認為，將大部分人工智慧恐懼解讀為資本主義恐懼最為恰當

I believe 將 is acting like 把 in this sentence. My understanding is that that form is

S + 將 + O + Verb Phrase, but I'm having trouble identifying the parts of speech accordingly.

Is the object = 大部分人工智慧恐懼 and the verb 解讀, then 為 starts another clause? What's the subject?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, "将" here can be regarded as "把."

And the subject is omitted, it can be "我们," "本文," "人类," or any other suitable word(s). Generally, you can find it somewhere in the context.

The translation for this sentence could be:

"I prefer that it is more suitable - in most cases - to regard the panic for AI as the panic for capitalism."

It is the same here. Which do you think is the subject in this translation? Can the subject be "it"?

Answer (score 1):

I think "最為恰當" is the subject.

- 你認為什麼觀點最為恰當?
- 我傾向於認為, 最為恰當的觀點是將大部分人工智慧恐懼解讀為資本主義恐懼.

Comment: Is it common for the subject to be at the end of the sentence?

Comment: 恰當是什麼? = 什麼是恰當? It is not unusual.

Comment: "最為恰當" is the object complement. The object is 將大部分人工智慧恐懼解讀為資本主義恐懼. The prediction is 認為。

Answer (score 1):

The subject is omitted, it could be "we" or "people"

[將] **take**

[大部分人工智慧**恐懼**] **object**:(most of the **fear** toward A.I)

[**解讀**為資本主義恐懼] **verb**: (**interpret** as fear toward capitalism)

[最為恰當] comment: (is most appropriate)

> 我傾向於認為，將大部分人工智慧恐懼解讀為資本主義恐懼最為恰當

correct sentence:

> 我傾向於認為，將大部分(對)人工智慧(的)恐懼解讀為(對)資本主義(的)恐懼最為恰當

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, 将 is acting as 把 to indicate the object of an action. The full breakdown is:

我傾向于认为 (Subject)
将 (Object marker)
大部分人工智慧恐惧 (Object)
解读为 (Verb)
资本主义恐惧 (Complement)
最为恰当 (Adverbial modifier)

So the subject is 我傾向于认为 "I tend to think", the object is 大部分人工智慧恐惧 "most AI fears", and the verb is 解读为 "interpret as". The complement 资本主义恐惧 "fear of capitalism" provides more detail about the interpretation, and 最为恰当 "most appropriate" is an adverbial modifier describing the interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sentence 我傾向於認為，將大部分人工智慧恐懼解讀為資本主義恐懼最為恰當 is a translation from English. I would like to re-write it to have it more genuine in Chinese.

我傾向於認為，人们將大部分对人工智慧的恐懼解讀為对資本主義的恐懼，这是最為恰當的。

There are 3 basic sentence structures.

(1) 認為什么(object)**是**什么(complement)。For example，我認為这样的理解**是**恰當的。

(2) 將什么(object)**作为**什么(complement)。For example，人们将假说**作为**真理。

(3) 对什么(object)的**感觉**。= an OV structure as a noun phrase。For example，我对这个人的**感觉**不好。= 我**感觉**这个人不好。= I think he is not a good man.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to understand your difficulty by comparing the english translation, since there exists some differences when you try to apply an english grammar of thinking.

我傾向於認為，將大部分人工智慧恐懼解讀為資本主義恐懼最為恰當
when you translate it into english, it's like
"*I tend to think, it is most appropriate to explain most part of the fear  of AI as the fear of capitalism*."
In this long english sentence, what is the subject? I. verb? tend. complement? to think + clause

Then in the clause, what's the subject? It, or more precisely, 'It' as the formal subject of the sub-clause "To explain the fear of AI as the fear of captialism".
Since "it is adj. to do sth." is equivalent to "To do sth. is adj." In chinese we don't have such formal subject so we put the entire sub-clause before which makes the 主谓结构（I will not say SV structure as 谓语 can be acted by an adjective, see below) unbalanced. The worse thing is here not like english, the "be" verb doesn't exist actually, just like the case:
我很好 I am fine. (there is no 是）**this is because "subject + adj." is a valid form of 主谓结构**, **there is no verb in the clause**. There is no need to stiffly add the verb 是 (like transforming 我很好 to 我是好的) as some other answers did.

**Then it's quite easy to recognize 将 as a general proposition used together the a verb (here with 解读为).**

Finally 將大部分人工智慧恐懼解讀為資本主義恐懼 is just a long noun phrase, which we don't need to explicitly point out the subject as we say "To do sth." we don't specify the subject either.